# How to create a menu tree that will show all files in an USB flash drive?

Tags: flash, usb-flash-drive

I need to create a menu that will show all files in USB.
The menu will need to auto-run when inserting the USB.

the menu need to be dynamic, so if i will add files i will see the new files in the next time that i will use the USB.

the menu can be in any technology, i thought about flash.

Comment: Adobe Flash has nothing to do with the USB **flash** drive!

Comment: vulkanino - i know, maybe someone have an idea how to perform it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight Flash, to my knowledge, does not have the ability to list directories, but I think Adobe Air supports libraries for that.

You might try C++/C# if you're running on windows, or Java if you want this to be cross platform.